# How to pass multiple variables from twig to symfony controller action with render

Tags: symfony, twig

I am attempting to render an action from within twig to list results of a table. The first variable is passing through fine and I am getting the list populated, but the second variable is not arriving.

```
{% render 'RiskAssessmentBundle:Assessment:assessmentlist' with {'offenderId': entity.getId, 'assessmentStatus': 'Complete' } %}
```

Above is the render call in my twig template.  offenderId is arriving with a value.

```
    /**
 * List widget
 *
 * @param int $offenderId   id of the offender
 * @param string $assessmentStatus   const value of desired status
 *
 * @Template("RiskAssessmentBundle:Assessment:assessmentlist.html.twig")
 */
public function assessmentlistAction($offenderId, $assessmentStatus = null)
{
    var_dump($assessmentStatus);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $offender = $em->getRepository('RiskOffenderBundle:Offender')->find($offenderId);

    if (is_null($assessmentStatus)) {
        $assessments = $em->getRepository('RiskAssessmentBundle:Assessment')
            ->findAllByActive(true, $offenderId, 5);
    } else {
        $assessments = $em->getRepository('RiskAssessmentBundle:Assessment')
            ->findAllByStatus($assessmentStatus, $offenderId, 5);
    }

    return array(
        'assessments' => $assessments,
        'offender' => $offender,
    );
}
```

Above is the action called. The var_dump of the $assessmentStatus is always NULL.  I am new to symfony, but every piece of documentation I can find makes me think this should work.  Anyone have a clue what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Oh balls...I have a typo in the title.

Answer (score 0):

The above code works perfectly.  We have an extension system running and the entire twig template had been extended. The render I modified was not the render being called. Once I modified the other template it all works perfectly.